# Ffmpeg converted videos (longer than 30s) not playing in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, drupal, ffmpeg, video.js

As the title says, I'm having issues with converted videos that are over 30s. They are not playing in chrome but they do work in all other browsers. The thing is, if the video is less than 30s than it plays fine in chrome too.

The input file is `mpeg4` encoded and I'm trying to convert it using the `h264` codec. The conversion is done on a linux server with the help of a drupal module which converts the video on upload automatically.

This is the command and output:

```
/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i '/var/www/html/website/videos/original/2016-02-02-16-52-44-758_1.mp4' -strict experimental -vcodec 'libx264' -pix_fmt 'yuv420p' -vprofile 'baseline' -an -pass '1' -passlogfile '/tmp/1454496233-56b1d9e99deb8-multipass'  -y /tmp/1454496233-56b1d9e99dd6f.mp4
ffmpeg version N-61041-g52a2138 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar  2 2014 05:45:04 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-1)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit --extra-cflags='-I/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/include -static' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/lib -static' --extra-libs='-lxml2 -lexpat -lfreetype' --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/html/website/videos/original/2016-02-02-16-52-44-758_1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:54.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 840 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 839 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
[libx264 @ 0x38799c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x38799c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x38799c0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x38799c0] 264 - core 129 r2230 1cffe9f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0 me=dia subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/1454496233-56b1d9e99dd6f.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, pass 1, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 -> libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  129 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=     298kB time=00:00:03.41 bitrate= 715.2kbits/s    
frame=  268 fps=267 q=28.0 size=     784kB time=00:00:09.20 bitrate= 697.3kbits/s    
frame=  409 fps=271 q=28.0 size=    1313kB time=00:00:15.08 bitrate= 712.9kbits/s    
frame=  547 fps=272 q=28.0 size=    1744kB time=00:00:20.83 bitrate= 685.8kbits/s    
frame=  687 fps=274 q=28.0 size=    2275kB time=00:00:26.66 bitrate= 699.0kbits/s    
frame=  827 fps=275 q=28.0 size=    2754kB time=00:00:32.50 bitrate= 694.1kbits/s    
frame=  967 fps=275 q=28.0 size=    3273kB time=00:00:38.33 bitrate= 699.4kbits/s    
frame= 1106 fps=275 q=28.0 size=    3826kB time=00:00:44.12 bitrate= 710.2kbits/s    
frame= 1245 fps=276 q=28.0 size=    4366kB time=00:00:49.91 bitrate= 716.6kbits/s    
frame= 1306 fps=268 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4762kB time=00:00:54.41 bitrate= 716.8kbits/s
video:4756kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.125035%
[libx264 @ 0x38799c0] frame I:6     Avg QP:17.10  size: 43459
[libx264 @ 0x38799c0] frame P:1300  Avg QP:20.34  size:  3545
[libx264 @ 0x38799c0] mb I  I16..4: 31.1%  0.0% 68.9%
[libx264 @ 0x38799c0] mb P  I16..4:  3.7%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 14.8%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:81.5%
[libx264 @ 0x38799c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 29.2% 62.3% 14.8% inter: 3.4% 5.8% 0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x38799c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 58% 22% 17%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x38799c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 59% 24%  8%  1%  1%  1%  2%  1%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x38799c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 36% 14% 47%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x38799c0] kb/s:715.83
```

I also tried with the latest version of ffmpeg but I have the same problem.
Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

Note that this is a log from doing a two-pass encoding (it was the only way to get a log from drupal). The two-pass encoding works if I specify a bitrate in the ffmpeg command, but as I said, it doesn't work on chrome but works on all other browsers.

Comment: Do you have an example file?

Comment: I managed to fix this issue by adding qt-faststart as a helper program in the drupal's configurations. See the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add qt-faststart as a helper program in drupal's UI.

Go to `Configuration>Media>Video`, expand `Helper Programs` and put the path to `qt-faststart` there. It should be in your ffmpeg binary folder.

[image]